# How can I control the geometry that is included in ggplot2 legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, legend, shapes

I'd like to know how I can modify the geometry that appears in my legends.

Here's the example I have:

```
stockmlp %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = RMSE, x = Depth, color = Depth)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(size = 10, alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Stock, scales="free_y")
```

[geom_boxplot with geom_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQS5.png)

I think that `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list( )))` might work, but I don't know what to put in the list.

I want to remove the boxplot frame from the color legend so that it only shows a colored circle.

Comment: You can control the geoms that appear in the legend using the option `show.legend = F` on one of your geoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change which `geoms` are being shown in the legend with the `guides` function, you can only change their appearance (e.g. title, aesthetics...).

One option here is to have the `color` aesthetics applying only to the points by not specifying it in the main `ggplot` call but only the the `geom_point` one but this results in the boxplots not to be colored:

```
stockmlp %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = RMSE, x = Depth)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(size = 10, alpha = 0.5, aes(color = Depth)) +
  facet_wrap(~Stock, scales="free_y")
```

The better option is to specify not to show legend inside a `geom` call:

```
stockmlp %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = RMSE, x = Depth, color = Depth)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(size = 10, alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Stock, scales="free_y")
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the grey background behind the legend you can use the following:

`+ theme(legend.key = element_blank())`

Left is removed, right is default:

[image: removed]
[image: present]